What is the correct way to drop voltage in circuit?
I designed the schematic shown below for my automotive GPS tracker.

Here I used diodes for dropping the voltage. Main regulator D17 used for 5 to 3.8 V approx. Auto bat circuit D7 used as 4 - 3.8 V approx.
I'm thinking that is it the correct way to do this for long run
or any better way to do this?
Please give your suggestions and recommendations.

Have you tried simulating this circuit and seen how the MOSFET may not do what you want?

You need some protective elements for the 12 V DC from the car. The automotive environment is very harsh. There may be transients of 40 V and even more. Read https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Introduction%20to%20Automotive%20Linear%20Voltage%20Regulators%20BR-2014.pdf?fileId=5546d46146d18cb40147440c4569288d very carefully.
